# GoTo inside `if` branching?

Tags: c#, goto

I've a `goto` question: is it possible to go to a label that is down a local scope?
The below code can't find the `InsideTrue` label:

```cs
goto InsideTrue; // error CS0159: No such label 'InsideTrue' within the scope of the goto statement
if (true)
{
    InsideTrue:
    Console.WriteLine("true");
    goto OutsideIf;
}
else
{
    InsideFalse:
    Console.WriteLine("false");
    goto OutsideIf;
}
OutsideIf:
```

I would want to use that as a special branching case to bypass the `if/else` check on certain circumstances, how can I achieve that, without recompiling?

Comment: `how can I achieve that, without recompiling?` with another `if` block, instead of goto-directives which are concidered "bad practice" in virtually all circumstances? maybe if you're more specific about what exactly you're trying to _achieve_, we can find a way to do so without resorting to `goto` (TL;DR: goto is _always_ a bad choice)

Comment: No No No ... No GOTOs! Forget that it is supported and never use it!

Comment: _"... without recompiling?"_ - Not at all.

Comment: Just kidding, you choose your username because you need to post a question about prehistoric issues? :-)

Comment: Goto is no more.. Most new languages completely got rid of it. Older languages have it just for backward compatibility.. You can do any logic without Goto

Comment: I did not post question on my username's shake, but hey, that's a valid questionning.
The real use case I have is more complex: I've to debug inside some (real) if branches, but I can't go inside of them because they are not compiled, so I would want to force the execution flow to go through what's inside - I thought Goto could make a valid testing solution.

Comment: `but I can't go inside of them because they are not compiled` - that seems like there's something _terribly_ wrong in your code base, and you should refactor _immediatelly._ **fix** the architectural problem, instead of making it worse by goto-monkeypatching

Comment: _"and you should refactor immediatelly"_ .. to something that is unit testable. And then write unit tests.

Comment: goto should be avoided. Point. But I don't believe in religious assumptions where you need to have faith and close your eyes. I can't imagine now a situation where goto are truly a necessity but I can't exclude the possibility either. Sometime the cost to resolve a complex situation without goto could be so high that you will be tempted. However the problem in your question is just here. You have still not convinced anyone with facts that you really need one or more goto

Comment: The error message would seem to answer the question: No, you cannot `goto` a label that is not reachable from the current scope. [The specifiation](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-goto-statement) is even more definitive: "... if the `goto` statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs. This rule permits the use of a `goto` statement to transfer control out of a nested scope, but not into a nested scope." Also, if you can't recompile the `if ... else ...` then how can you recompile to `goto`, either?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews: can you post that as an answer, please? I'd make it the real "answer", because of scoping problems.
Edit: the non-recompilation constraint was there to avoid the `#if` proposals. I could use that instead of gotos, but I strongly prefer ugly `goto` statements over magically-defined variables.

Comment: If someone comes in with a workaround (like @yam-marcovic below), I'll consider them aswell.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `goto` used nicely, except that there's so much `religion` and `emotions` about it due to some papers.

Comment: @Joelty But very rarely is it ever used nicely. It is only actually useful when jumping out of doubly-nested blocks (when you should probably refactor into functions) or in certain highly optimized algorithms, where conditional branching is undesirable etc. The vast majority of uses in the wild should be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @LanceU.Matthews, the jump is not permitted.

I quote their answer here :

> The error message would seem to answer the question: No, you cannot goto a label that is not reachable from the current scope.
> [The specifiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-goto-statement) is even more definitive: "... if the goto statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs.
> This rule permits the use of a goto statement to transfer control out of a nested scope, but not into a nested scope."

Thanks for the answer, refactor (by *butch..* extracting the content of the `if`) was a very neat out-of-the-box thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible, but to entertain us all, you could extract the code inside the if/else to other labels:

```
goto InsideTrue;
if (true)
{
    goto InsideTrue;
}
else
{
    goto InsideFalse;
}
InsideTrue:
Console.WriteLine("true");
goto OutsideIf;
InsideFalse:
Console.WriteLine("false");
OutsideIf:
```

Comment: **warning**: please don't ever use code like this, except as a joke. otherwise you run the risk of some other developer reading your code at some point in the future, and instantly hating you. penalisation by coffee deprivation might occur.

Comment: upvote for the good laugh, I thought labels could only be used to break out of loops in C#

Comment: I've commented my op to clarify the use-case a little, I'll not be able to implement your answer as-is, but it may be a valid answer to the OP question.
I'll wait until any other fancy solution might show up.

Comment: That's what the Lawful Evil case would look like in the Alignment Charts meme

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't use it, but other people already said it so I'll not elaborate on this.

Second the problem that you encounter is that the `InsideTrue` declaration is out of the scope at the first line. This is because it hasn't been declared at this position of your code.

You will have to rethink your code to declare `InsideTrue` out of the `if` (I know this is what you want but it can't be done that way), because at the runtime there's no way to know if you're going to enter the `if`, preventing the declaration of `InsideTrue` until you're inside it.

Goto (really, stop using it) is used to **exit** switch statements or loops with a Labeled Statement outside of it, to avoid code that is not required